# Java Servlet/JSP Custom Error Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, try-catch

I have a custom error page setup for basic debugging whilst I'm programming and for some reason none of the values from the try catches get through. The error page just says: "Null null null". If anyone can help with this I'd be very grateful.

Servlet:

```
package com.atrium.userServlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.atrium.DAOs.UserDAO;
import com.atrium.userBeans.UserRegistrationBean;

@WebServlet("/Register")
public class UserRegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserRegistrationServlet() {

        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

            if (session == null) {

                response.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext() + "/Authenticate");
                return;

            }

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

        catch(Throwable exception) {

            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            Throwable errorCause = exception.getCause();
            String errorLocation = this.getServletName();

            request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", errorMessage);
            request.setAttribute("ErrorCause", errorCause);
            request.setAttribute("ErrorLocation", errorLocation);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errorDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {       

            String ErrorMessage = "";

            //Check user name is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("Username") == null || request.getParameter("Username") == "") {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter a username!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check user name for maximum length

            if (request.getParameter("Username").length() > 16) {

                ErrorMessage = "The username you entered was too long! Only 16 characters are allowed.";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check password is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("Password") == null || request.getParameter("Password") == "") {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter a password!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check verify password is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("vPassword") == null || request.getParameter("vPassword") == "") {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter your password twice!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check password is equal to verify password

            if (((String)request.getParameter("Password")).equals((String)request.getParameter("vPassword"))) {}
            else {

                ErrorMessage = "The passwords you entered do not match!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check password for complexity

            /*--------------------------------------------------------
            (?=.*[0-9]) a digit must occur at least once
            (?=.*[a-z]) a lower case letter must occur at least once
            (?=.*[A-Z]) an upper case letter must occur at least once
            (?=[\\S]+$) no whitespace allowed in the entire string
            .{6,16} at least 6 to 16 characters 
            ---------------------------------------------------------*/

            Pattern passwordPattern = Pattern.compile("((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=[\\S]+$).{6,16})");

            Matcher passwordMatcher = passwordPattern.matcher(request.getParameter("Password"));

            if (passwordMatcher.find() == false) {

                ErrorMessage = "The password you entered does not abide by the strength rules!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check email is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("Email") == null || request.getParameter("Username") == "") {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter an email!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check verify email is supplied

            if (request.getParameter("vEmail") == null || request.getParameter("vEmail") == "") {

                ErrorMessage = "You must enter your email twice!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Check email is equal to verify email

            if (((String)request.getParameter("Email")).equals((String)request.getParameter("vEmail"))) {}
            else {

                ErrorMessage = "The emails you entered did not match!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            //Validate email - *@*

            Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(request.getParameter("Email"));

            if (emailMatcher.find() == false) {

                ErrorMessage = "The email you entered is not valid!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

            UserRegistrationBean user = new UserRegistrationBean();
            user.setUsername(request.getParameter("Username"));
            user.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));
            user.setEmail(request.getParameter("Email"));

            user = UserDAO.register(user);

            if (user.getExists() == true) {

                ErrorMessage = "The user name you entered has already been registered!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }

        }

        catch(Throwable exception) {

            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            Throwable errorCause = exception.getCause();
            String errorLocation = this.getServletName();

            request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", errorMessage);
            request.setAttribute("ErrorCause", errorCause);
            request.setAttribute("ErrorLocation", errorLocation);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errorDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }

    }

}
```

JSP Error Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Exception Details</title>

</head>

<body>

    <% final String errorMessage = (String)request.getAttribute("ErrorMessage"); %>
    <% final Throwable errorCause = (Throwable)request.getAttribute("ErrorCause"); %>
    <% final String errorLocation = (String)request.getAttribute("ErrorLocation"); %>

    <h1>An Error Occurred...</h1>

    <p>



        <%= errorMessage %><br><br>

        <%= errorCause %><br><br>



    <%= errorLocation %>

</p>
```

Comment: 1. ErrorLocation vs. Location mismatch. 2. why is the jsp in web-inf? put it in the war folder, and simply direct to it: "errorDisplay.jsp"

Comment: All of my JSPs are stored in WEB-INF since it ensures the user cannot access them without going through the servlet, the user MUST go through the servlet or dynamic function will not work. I've fixed the mismatch though, thanks. Although that doesn't actually solve anything.

Comment: Do you do something similar to that in other places? what about the space in "Error Cause"?

Comment: @Infested I removed the space, and what part are you referring to when you say something similar? Accessing the JSP in the WEB-INF? Yes, and it works.

Comment: If this is for basic debugging, what about not catching the exception and letting it bubble up ... the container should display the exception with the stack trace?

Comment: you dont String error cause in the servlet?

Comment: It doesn't seem to, or at least I don't know where Tomcat releases this information. Besides, this is coursework and I was told explicitly by my tutor to capture all exceptions myself.

Comment: @Infested No, because it throws errors whenever I attempt to typecast it.

Comment: but you try to read it as a string in the jsp

Comment: @Infested I know, I'm just trying to find the cause of the issue with the first one, errorMessage and then I'll work out why it won't typecast and what data type I need to use.

Comment: try in the servlet to first make variables according to the things you want to send and set those as attributes. and also it may be that there are leftovers from where the user was sent from to this servlet.

Comment: also - can you post the redirecting code as well?

Comment: @Infested I updated the code in the question, that code makes the location variable work, will edit the JSP in a second. The redirection is performed by the request dispatcher.

Comment: @Infested Updated the JSP code, errorMessage and errorCause still come out as "null"

Comment: So its something to do with the throwable, but im not too sure about why; i myself have used local variables and they were passed on.. try cloning and not just assigning.

Comment: @Infested What do you mean by cloning and not assigning? I'm new to this sort of thing.

Comment: in java everything is a pointer, with strings and many complex types things get nasty, assigning a = b in many of these types simply sets a to point where b points. so here try cloning - really building it as a separate but same thing.

Comment: @Infested Ok, so how do I clone a variable rather than point at it?

Comment: you can use new String etc etc... can you post more code please? also code from the file that sends the user to this servlet

Comment: @Infested I'll update the answer with the full servlet, no servlet directs to this one.

Comment: what are you doing? why are you using getParameter for the same thing over and over?

Comment: @Infested I updated the code in the question. Essentially the user goes to this servlet via a link on the home page, which doesn't exist yet (so going to it directly via URL). They then enter the details into the form, submit it, and if there's an error they're redirected to the error page with an error report for debugging purposes.

Comment: are you sure it goes to the catch you want it to? does location print ok still? try without the final?

Comment: @Infested Yeah location prints just fine, I'll try remove the final types.
EDIT: No difference.

Comment: can you log/print the things you pass - in the servlet? (to see if they are null or simply do not pass)

Comment: @Infested Both of them come out as null still.

Comment: @Infested Just printed the exception directly and it came out as a null pointer exception.

Comment: well there you go, thats your problem.

Comment: @Infested But that's not why the error page won't work.

Comment: if the exception doesnt point anywhere.. all its stuff will be null as well, so its logical that what the errorDisplay will get will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes to your catch block:

```
catch(Throwable errorMessage) {

            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", (String)errorMessage.getMessage());
            request.setAttribute("errorCause", errorMessage.getCause());
            request.setAttribute("errorLocation", (String)this.getServletName());

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errorDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

Try this on your jsp page:

```
<body>
    <h1>An Error Occurred...</h1>

    <p>



        ${requestScope.errorMessage}<br><br>

        ${requestScope.errorCause}<br><br>

        ${requestScope.errorLocation}

    </p>

</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have made a difference, when the JSP is setup like that it outputs "ErrorMessage" onto the page and that's it.

Comment: what is it supposed to output? .. it seems like it's passing null for the errorCause and errorLocation?

Comment: When an error occurs somewhere else in a servlet or whatever the user is redirected to this page and the exception details are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an error handler servlet like this :

```
@WebServlet("/error")
public class ErrorHandler extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /***** This Method Is Called By The Servlet Container To Process A 'GET' Request *****/
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        handleRequest(request, response);
    }

    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /***** Analyze The Servlet Exception *****/        
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        String servletName = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");
        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");

        if (servletName == null) {
            servletName = "Unknown";
        }

        String requestUri = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");
        if (requestUri == null) {
            requestUri = "Unknown";
        }

        /***** Set Response Content Type *****/
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        /***** Print The Response *****/
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String title = "Error/Exception Information";       
        String docType = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
        out.println(docType 
                + "<html>\n" + "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" + "<body>");

        if (throwable == null && statusCode == null) {
            out.println("<h3>Error Information Is Missing</h3>");           
        } else if (statusCode != 500) {
            out.write("<h3>Error Details</h3>");
            out.write("<ul><li><strong>Status Code</strong>?= "+ statusCode + "</li>");
            out.write("<li><strong>Requested URI</strong>?= "+ requestUri + "</li></ul>");
        } else {
            out.println("<h3>Exception Details</h3>");
            out.println("<ul><li><strong>Servlet Name</strong>?= " + servletName + "</li>");
            out.println("<li><strong>Exception Name</strong>?= " + throwable.getClass( ).getName( ) + "</li>");
            out.println("<li><strong>Requested URI</strong>?= " + requestUri + "</li>");
            out.println("<li><strong>Exception Message</strong>?= " + throwable.getMessage( ) + "</li></ul>");
        }

        out.println("<div> </div>Click <a id=\"homeUrl\" href=\"index.jsp\">home</a>");
        out.println("</body>\n</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Then register it to handle the error cases in `web.xml` like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
   <display-name>Error/Exception Information</display-name>

   <!-- Error Code Related Error Pages -->
   <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/error</location>
   </error-page>
   <error-page>
      <error-code>403</error-code>
      <location>/error</location>
   </error-page>
   <!-- Exception Type Related Error Pages -->
   <error-page>
      <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
      <location>/error</location>
   </error-page>
   <error-page>
      <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
      <location>/error</location>
   </error-page>
</web-app>
```

So you just need to throw the exception from all other servlets in case of any exception and it will be handled automatically by this error servlet that we have defined.So, throw the exception from your servlet like :

```
@WebServlet("/myExceptionServlet")
public class MyExceptionServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        throw new ServletException("HTTP GET Method Is Not Supported.");
    }
}
```