# Servlet - MySQL Error

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I'm trying to enter data into a MySQL database with the following code. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I just can't work out why there is an exception. The request parameters are supplied by a HTML form and there don't appear to be any issues with that at all, the data gets through just fine. The issue seems to be occurring after the servlet is done and is probably somewhere in the DAO or connection manager. Thanks SO MUCH in advance!

Relevant Servlet Code:

```
            UserRegistrationBean user = new UserRegistrationBean();
            user.setUsername(request.getParameter("Username"));
            user.setPassword(request.getParameter("Password"));
            user.setEmail(request.getParameter("Email"));

            user = UserDAO.register(user);

            if (user.getExists() == true) {

                ErrorMessage = "The user name you entered has already been registered!";

                request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", ErrorMessage);

                request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/register.jsp").forward(request, response);

                return;

            }
```

UserDAO:

```
public static UserRegistrationBean register(UserRegistrationBean bean) {

    Statement stmt = null;    

    String username = bean.getUsername();    
    String password = bean.getPassword();  
    String email = bean.getEmail();

    String searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE Username='"
                        + username
                        + "'";

    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('" 
                        + username + 
                        "', '" 
                        + password + 
                        "', '" 
                        + email +
                        "')";

    try {

        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        stmt = currentCon.createStatement();

        //check if user exists

        ResultSet searchRs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);

        //User name is available
        if (searchRs.next() == false) {

            bean.setExists(false);

        } 

        //User name is not available
        else if (searchRs.next() == true) {

            bean.setExists(true);

        }

        if (bean.getExists() == true) {

            //Return error and prevent registration

            bean.setSuccess(false);

            return bean;

        }

        else {

            stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);

            bean.setSuccess(true);

        }

    }

    catch(Exception ex) {

        //exception available here

    }

    return bean;

}
```

ConnectionManager:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    static Connection connection;
    static String url;

    public static Connection getConnection() {

        try {

            String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + "localhost:3306"; 

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            try {

            connection = DriverManager
                      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/the_atrium_beauty?"
                          + "user=System&password=sYstem~9");

        }

            catch (SQLException ex) {

                //Stack trace available here
                //ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {

            //Exception check available here
            //System.out.println(e);

        }

        return connection;

    }
}
```

Try Catch Block:

```
catch(Throwable exception) {

            String errorMessage = exception.getMessage();
            Throwable errorCause = exception.getCause();
            String errorLocation = this.getServletName();

            request.setAttribute("ErrorMessage", errorMessage);
            request.setAttribute("ErrorCause", errorCause);
            request.setAttribute("ErrorLocation", errorLocation);

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/errorDisplay.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }
```

Error Display JSP:

```
<body>

    <% final String errorMessage = (String)request.getAttribute("ErrorMessage"); %>
    <% final Throwable errorCause = (Throwable)request.getAttribute("ErrorCause"); %>
    <% final String errorLocation = (String)request.getAttribute("ErrorLocation"); %>

    <h1>An Error Occurred...</h1>

    <p>

        <%= errorMessage %><br><br>

        <%= errorCause %><br><br>

        <%= errorLocation %>

    </p>

</body>
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.atrium.userServlets.UserRegistrationServlet.doPost(UserRegistrationServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You've said you get an error, but you haven't told us what it is, and there's no stack trace for us to work with. Could you update your question and provide us with them? Also, as an observation, you're executing an *update* statement using `executeQuery()` instead of `executeUpdate()`.

Comment: post ur errorstacktrace.

Comment: You should really do something with exceptions, at least print them somewhere!

Comment: Why are you not using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as your DB driver? sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver is very much out of date and should be avoided.

Comment: Will make those changes now, I'm having an issue with my method of fetching exceptions at the moment and am trying to fix it. Will put up the exception message ASAP.

Comment: Is there anyway I can setup my tomcat inside eclipse to output this exception to the console?

Comment: I'd start by un-commenting the calls to `printStackTrace()` in your `catch` blocks...

Comment: @JonK I have a servlet where I'm actually handling the exception, I'm waiting to get it right there first so I can copy and paste the code to all of my try and catch blocks. I'll put that try and catch in the question now.

Comment: @JonK I added the stack trace.

Comment: Ok - now we need to know which line of your posted `UserRegistrationServlet` is line 231

Comment: @JonK This one: if (user.getExists() == true) {

Comment: Which implies that `user` is `null` or the return value of `getExists()` is `null` (is the return type a `Boolean` object?). Have you debugged through your `register` method to see why it's returning a `null` value?

Comment: @JonK Yeah the variable in the bean is Boolean, could it be null because there's something wrong with the SQL query? Or something wrong with the connection to the MySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies here (condensed code slightly for readability):

```java
ResultSet searchRs = stmt.executeQuery(searchQuery);

//User name is available
if (searchRs.next() == false) {
    bean.setExists(false);
} 

//User name is not available
else if (searchRs.next() == true) {
    bean.setExists(true);
}

if (bean.getExists() == true) {
    //Return error and prevent registration
    bean.setSuccess(false);
    return bean;
}
```

`next()` *moves the `ResultSet`'s internal cursor on to the next row*. The implication of this is that subsequent calls to `next()` are *not guaranteed to return the same result*.

So this:

```java
if (searchRs.next() == false) {
```

Might not return the same thing as this a few lines later:

```java
else if (searchRs.next() == true) {
```

This means that there is a potential pathway through this code where *neither* condition is ever true. Specifically, if the first invokation of `next()` returns `true` and the second invokation returns `false`, neither branch will execute.

There's a whole bunch of approaches to fixing this. Personally I would do this:

```java
// Check the true condition first, no need for == true
if (searchRs.next()) {
    // User already exists
    bean.setExists(true);
    bean.setSuccess(false);

    // Returning the bean object isn't strictly necessary because of side-effects
    return bean;
} else {
    // User doesn't already exist
    bean.setExists(false);
    stmt.executeUpdate(insertQuery);

    // You'll need to commit the transaction for it to work properly:
    currentCon.commit();
    bean.setSuccess(true);

    return bean;
}
```

Essentially, because the `boolean` comparisons in this context can *only ever have two outcomes*, you can use `if {} else {}` instead of `if {} else if {}`.

**Note:** I am assuming that the return type of `getExists()` is `Boolean` instead of `boolean` (because `boolean` can't be `null`). With that in mind, I believe that you're not initialising the variable that sits behind `getExists()` because of the problem above, so it's still set at its default value, which for objects is `null`.

Because the changes to `bean` are [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), you don't actually need to return it from the method, the changes to the object should be visible outside of the method as well.

---

For your exception handling it would be (very) useful if you didn't swallow it up without reporting it. Presumably the calling method needs to know that something unusual has gone wrong, so rather than catch and do nothing, do something like this instead:

```java
try {
    // Your database access code here
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // You don't want to persist any dud data, so rollback the connection
    currentCon.rollback();

    // Propagates the exception upward to the calling method
    throw new RegistrationException("Error registering user", e);
}
```

Where `RegistrationException` is a custom exception class that you create yourself (You should define at least a constructor that takes a `String` and a `Throwable` as arguments). You will have to modify your method signature to declare the exception as well:

```java
public static UserRegistrationBean register(UserRegistrationBean bean)
        throws RegistrationException {
```

This forces the calling method to either re-throw (thus further propagating) the exception or handle it.

Comment: Awesome answer right there, very detailed and I'm sure it fixed part of the problem for me but the same error is still occurring. Something is still going wrong somewhere. Could the SQL query not be executing correctly and therefore not returning a resultset?

Comment: @TOFFster If the query wasn't executing properly I would expect to see some description of `SQLException` being thrown. As you're blanket catching and then doing nothing with it (always a bad idea), it's entirely possible that the first statement is failing, thus leaving your `Boolean` uninitialised. Could you propagate the exception upwards or print the stack trace and see what happens?

Comment: The stack trace in the question is the one being produced at the moment. What do you mean by propagate the exception?

Comment: @TOFFster In the `catch` block, rather than doing nothing instead rethrow the exception, perhaps with your own message added to it (and maybe use a custom exception too). I'll update my answer with a suggestion for it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm still not 100% sure what you mean but I expect the example will shed some light on it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a bit more sense to me now. Custom exception handling is probably a bit beyond my skill level and the skill level my tutor knows I have, would be best if I don't include it but I think I get the jist of it. Thanks for teaching me it. I'll include the connection rollback too.

Comment: @TOFFster I also just added line of code to part of the original answer to commit the newly inserted user (it might not be necessary if your database is set to auto-commit, but it's best to be on the safe side). Custom exceptions aren't anything special - they're just another type of object. They just happen to have `Throwable` in their class heirarchy. You should be able to work out how to do it just by looking at the source code for something like `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the heads up. I'll include that too. If you had the time, would it be possible for me to contact you on a private address? Email? Skype? That would be unbelievably helpful for me and I'm sure I could give you something in return if you wanted.

Comment: @TOFFster Given that this is supposed to be a freely available community that helps answer questions, I wouldn't accept anything for answering a question - gratitude is more than enough! I don't mind if you want to contact me outside of SO - though I'd prefer not to post contact details in a public place...

Comment: Fair enough, I can tweet at you. I see your twitter on your profile.

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old type-1 `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` which is common for all databases and it has many problems also. So my suggestion is to use a database specific driver and change connection URL accordingly.

**For Ex:**

If you are using mysql use

```
// this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<ip>/<db name>?"
              + "user=<username>&password=<password>");
```

Comment: yeah seems ok.. So what is problem now?

Comment: Ok, well I'm trying to work out how to make my tomcat (inside eclipse) show me the exception, it won't boot in debug mode. I have another question going at the moment regarding my custom exception jsp, if I can get that working then I'll be able to provide you with an exception that tells you what's wrong. Whenever I submit this HTML form I get an error, which I need to identify.

Comment: Seems you have a pile of problems but you are not sharing any of them. Share the exception and error stack trace then we can understand what is going wrong.

Comment: That's the problem at the moment, I'm trying to get the exception and stack trace but am unable. This shows the issue I'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267506/java-servlet-jsp-custom-error-page

Comment: I added a stack trace to the question.

Comment: problem in doPost method of servlet. Post the complete code of servlet nd JSP form.

Comment: Look at the comments below the original question, we identified the culprit and I'm going to try the answer above yours when I get the time.